# Using R with in command bash terminal

Tags: bash, r, shell

I have a set of files *.txt in a specific directory. I have written an `.r` file code called `SampleStatus.r` which contains a unique function that reads, proceeses data and writes the results to an output file.

The function is like:

```
format_windpro(import_file="in.txt", export_file="out.txt")
```

I would like to use `bash` commands to read and compute every file in one command using my R file.

Comment: Would you settle for using R entirely? I mean we can get R to list all the files and then run your function on each one in turn. See `?list.files` for example of a way to list the files in the a directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Rscript`. Example code:

```
for f in ${INPUT_DIR}/*.txt; do \
    base=$(basename $f) \
    Rscript SampleStatus.R $f ${OUTPUT_DIR}/$base \
done
```

While in your `SampleStatus.R` you handle command line arguments like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

# ...

argv <- commandArgs(T)

# error checking...

import_file <- argv[1]
export_file <- argv[2]

# your function call
format_windpro(import_file, export_file)
```

Comment: I prefer littler, the syntax i easier with many possibilities. More info on http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html

Comment: So, in order to understand this. Where should I type the second commands for SampleStatus.r??
Thanks

Comment: @Jonel_R these are not commands, it's the file's contents. I suggest here that you edit your `SampleStatus.R`. If you cannot edit the file, you could rename (using `mv`) `in.txt` and `out.txt` in the bash script inside the loop.